# Concept behind multi-column vs. multiple single-column indexing

Tags: mysql, indexing, tree

I've been reading up on mySQL indexing recently and would like to see if my understanding of multi-indexing is right on track. I primarily use InnoDB.

I'll use the following query as an example:

`SELECT * FROM tbl_test WHERE col1=X AND col2=Y`

**Multi-column Index**

Assuming there is an index:

`CREATE INDEX idx_multi ON tbl(col1,col2,col3)`

The entire index is concatenated somehow (The simplest would be to add a delimiter inbetween, e.g. a comma) and store them directly into B-tree. The structure of the B-tree forces a index-check from left to right (since the index is now stored as a string? <-- Can someone delve into this?) Thus, there is only a single B-tree search on `idx_multi`.

**Multiple Single-column Indexes**

`CREATE INDEX idx_col1 ON tbl(col1)`

`CREATE INDEX idx_col2 ON tbl(col2)`

`CREATE INDEX idx_col3 ON tbl(col3)`

The Parser searches the B-trees of both `idx_col1` and `idx_col2`, returns the 2 respective sets of rows and then runs an `INTERSECT` to obtain the result (mySQL Index Merge Optimization). In this case, the engine runs 2 B-tree searches before executing an additional query.

I have another question:
For the B-tree implementation for indexes, does have an INT index make searching more efficient than a VARCHAR index?

I'd appreciate it if anyone could point out the flaws in my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Short answers:

- "Index merge intersect" is less efficient than a good composite index.
- `VARCHAR` is only slightly less efficient than `INT`; don't worry about it.
- Changing `PRIMARY KEY(string)` to `PRIMARY KEY(id), UNIQUE(string)` usually hurts performance.
- Your `idx_multi` *concept* is correct.

The Long answer is too long for this format, but I have provided it in my [discussion of composite indexes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1) and my [index cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).